# Why Relativelayout doesn't work on fragments?

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, android-relativelayout

I have created a bottom navigation bar from this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JS3DIb4x1JQ&t=1352s, but RelativeLayout doesn't work properly on fragments.
Here is the code of bluetooth fragment with textview in the middle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bluetooth"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#0472FE"
        android:text="Bluetooth"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is what it looks like in
 [design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXizb.jpg)

And this is what it looks like in
[android emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpUry.jpg)

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Are there other components in this view? check the main view if it set to `match_parent`.